# on click input type date but var $(#date).value is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" required>
```

whin I click on type="date"  alert is showing.
How I get the date with I click on the date input.

```
<script>
$("#date").click(function () {
  var date = $('#date').val(); 
    if(date == ''){
       alert('Error; Date is empty');
        return;
    }
    $('#name').html('');
    $('#name').html('<option>Select Name</option>');
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: 'recording.php',
      data : { date : date},
      success : function(data){
         $('#name').html(data);
      }

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, at the begining before you enter/choose date, you have to click on input field which will trigger alert that date is empty.

You should change your event to `change` instead of `click`, so when the change happens then check for date (change will happen on input lose focus or enter key inside of input):

Also after we get an event change, inside of it, we can use `$(this)` so we get the element that is currently changed in this case it is `#date`.

```
<script>
$("#date").on('change', function() {
  var date = $(this).val(); 
    if(date == ''){
       alert('Error; Date is empty');
        return;
    }
    $('#name').html('');
    $('#name').html('<option>Select Name</option>');
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: 'recording.php',
      data : { date : date},
      success : function(data){
         $('#name').html(data);
      }

    });
});
</script>
```